# chef cookbook install chrome centos7

Tags: google-chrome, chef-infra, centos7, cookbook

I am trying to install chrome on my centos 7 desktop using chefdk and local mode. chrome installs fine using yum directly, I am using this as a learning exercise in chef. So far it is failing on a dependency check for apt on both centos 7.2 and macosx 10.11.5. Details for centos only appear below. Base cookbooks, eg yum and apt install fine, so I am missing something here.
Thanks for any help.

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
Installed: yum-3.4.3-132.el7.centos.0.1.noarch 
using 
chefdk.x86_64                              0.15.15-1.el7               @/chefdk-0.15.15-1.el7.x86_64

knife cookbook show chrome
chrome   1.2.2
```

When I try to install:

```
sudo sudo chef-client --local-mode  --runlist 'recipe[chrome]' 2>&1 | tee  /export/cookbooks/install_chrome_from_cookbook.2.log
```

it tries to use apt and fails because of an apt version failure : see log below.

What could the problem be?

```
cat /export/cookbooks/install_chrome_from_cookbook.2.log

`    [2016-06-28T00:35:35-04:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
>   [2016-06-28T00:35:35-04:00] INFO: Auto-discovered chef repository at /export
>   [2016-06-28T00:35:36-04:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at     chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /export
>     One version per cookbook

>    [2016-06-28T00:35:36-04:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:36-04:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.11.18 ***
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:36-04:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:36-04:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 7293
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: GET /organizations/chef/nodes/nuctv-w.lfz.net
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to [#<Chef::RunList::RunListItem:0x00000004e13468 @version=nil, @type=:recipe, @name="chrome">] from CLI options
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[chrome]]
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: Run List expands to [chrome]
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for nuctv-w.lfz.net
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: Running start handlers
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: POST /organizations/chef/reports/nodes/nuctv-w.lfz.net/runs
>    --- POST BODY ---
>    {"action":"start","run_id":"8532d8c8-2e83-45e3-b867-f55f264a93df","start_time":"2016-06-28 00:35:38 -0400"}
>    --- END POST BODY ---
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: 
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:38-04:00] INFO: POST /organizations/chef/environments/_default/cookbook_versions
>    --- POST BODY ---
>    {"run_list":["chrome"]}
>    --- END POST BODY ---
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:39-04:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 412: Could not satisfy version constraints for: apt>
>    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/environment_cookbook_versions_endpoint.rb:42:in `post'
>    ....
>    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
>    /bin/chef-client:52:in `load'
>    /bin/chef-client:52:in `<main>'
>    [2016-06-28T00:35:39-04:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 412 Precondition Failed: Could not satisfy version constraints for: apt

>    ================================================================================
>    Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
>    ================================================================================

>    Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
Could not satisfy version constraints for: apt

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* chrome

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux

[2016-06-28T00:35:39-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2016-06-28T00:35:39-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-06-28T00:35:39-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-06-28T00:35:39-04:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-06-28T00:35:39-04:00] ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed"
[2016-06-28T00:35:40-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Chef dependencies are always required, even if they won't be used. If you use the more modern cookbook upload tools like Berkshelf or `chef push` it will take care of this for you.